# Nested Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a array like tree structure.

```
array = [["id":1,
          "child" = [subarray],
          "show" = true
          ]
          ["id":2,"child" = [
                ["id"  : 3,
                 "child" : [ "id":4,
                      "child"= [subarray],
                      "show" = true  
                      ]
                 "show" = true 
                  ]
               "show" = true
           ]
```

Tried Code:

```
for  (index, var dict) in arr.enumerate(){
    print(dict)
    let category = dict["id"] 

    if cateID == category.cat_id{
        let show = dict["show"] as! Bool
        dict["show"] = !show
        arr[index] = dict
        temp_foundDict = dict
    } else if dict["child"] != nil && (dict["show"] as! Bool){
        var arr1 = dict["child"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        print(arr1)
        self.Hide_ShowRow(cateID, arr: &arr1)
    }
}

return (arr)
```

Too much complicated code,but I written summarize code only.

If change value inside nested to nested array then it will not reflected to main array.

How can I achieve easily that if I changed nested to nested array then also reflect into main array?

Comment: share tried code.

Comment: One possible way is to create model of the array. Second one is replace the object you are changing.

Comment: This is not Swift code. What does the syntax `"show" = true` mean?

Comment: @NishantBhindi, model object will also create same problem as we don't have any event to notify main array .

Comment: @appzYourLife, means whether to show child or not

Comment: If you need a Tree then create a Node type and link several nodes togheter. Using an array here is a bad idea.

Comment: No model object always reference the property not replicate it unless and until you forcefully do that.

Comment: At a first glance would also mention using the class is better (or model like it was stated above). Code is too hard to read.